# Can there be an infinite number of different cycles in a directed graph?

Tags: graphs

If not, then what is the maximum number of cycles in any graph?

Comment: What are your thoughts?  I recommend consulting and making sure you understand the formal definition of a cycle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_%28graph_theory%29

Comment: Is the graph finite?

Answer (score 0):

If the graph has finite vertices then the no. of cycles are finite but for an infinite graph there can be infinite cycles.